# Perl, Seq.pl Script not running

Tags: perl

This is slightly linked to my last question in that I have no perl experience, but as part of my research paper I have to use this perl script (Which does not belong to me). I am having issues with it in that I can't seem to output anything:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# seq.pl
# Script to see how random session ID are.
############################################
use Math::BigInt;

@seq = ();
@x = @y = @z = (;
while(<>) {
chomp($val = $_);
push(@seq, $val);

}
for ($i = 3; $i < $#seq; $i++) {
push(@x, $seq[$i]       - $seq[$i - 1]);
push(@y, $seq[$i - 1]   - $seq[$i - 2]);
push(@z, $seq[$i - 2]   - $seq[$i - 3]);
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $#seq; $i++) {
print $x[$i] . " " . $y[$i] . " " . $z[$i] . "\n"; 
}
```

I am using this script to output co ordinates for a graph.
my questions are:
1) Where do i input the numbers
2)Do i need to specify an output file or anything? and if so how can i do this?

Sorry if they are stupid questions but I'm beginning to worry.
Thanks,
Alice

Comment: you should use it like this: `perl seq.pl < your_input.txt` (if you are on Linux/MacOSX/Unix). If you would like to save output to a file then: `perl seq.pl < your_input.txt > your_output.txt`. Otherwise it will print to screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(<>) {
```

It reads from STDIN using the diamond operator. So you can:

- Run the program and then start typing
- Pipe some data into it the output of another program (`foo | perl yourscript`)
- Pipe some data into it from a file (`perl yourscript < somefile.txt`)
- Pass filenames as arguments (`perl yourscript somefile.txt someotherfile.txt`)

  print $x[$i] . " " . $y[$i] . " " . $z[$i] . "\n";

It outputs to STDOUT, so the output will be displayed.

You can redirect it to a file. `perl yourscript somefile.txt > someoutput.txt`

Comment: Thank you! I am using the 3rd point that you suggested, but I am getting this error: syntax error at seq.pl line 9, near "(;"
Execution of seq1.pl aborted due to compilation errors

Comment: `)` is missing. It should be `@x = @y = @z = ();` not `@x = @y = @z = (;` @user3250789

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise pressing enter would send the comment. I have another very similar script to the one above and it has outputted me co ordinates, so THANK YOU VERY MUCH! but I am interested why the other one didn't work?